# Announce new sites when they reach beta and when they finally get released

Tags: discussion, feature-request, beta-sites

When a new site gets into beta (when moderators are chosen) and when the site lauches officially with its own skin (alpha?), please announce it in the side below `hot network questions` as `SE news` or some other suitable title.

I think this will call more attention to the site and kindle an interest in the site.

Comment: Maybe not when it gets into beta, maybe when the moderators are elected? A stream of bad traffic when a site is just finding it's footing won't be great...

Comment: @Tim That is a good idea. I will edit my question to reflect it.